# Passing function from .js to onBlur in html

Tags: javascript, html

I have this function in my .js that I want to put into my onBlur, but I' not having much luck on getting it to work.

.js
    var error = "";

```
function first(first)
{
    if(first == "")
    {
        error += "\nPlease enter your name";
        first.focus();
    }
    return first;
}
function validateAll()
{
    if (!error == "")
    {
        alert(error);
        return false;
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<p>First Name*:
<input type="textbox" name="first" id="first" onBlur="this.value=trim(this.value); first(this.value)" onkeyup='capitalize(this)'></p>

<p><input type="button" value="Proccess Payment" onClick="return validateAll();"/></p>
```

Basically I'm validating text box for first name in .js bring it over to HTML and putting the in onBlur and then validating it on click.

Comment: *"but I' not having much luck on getting it to work"* Please be more specific about *how* it does not work. What do you expect it to do and what does it currently do? Do you see any errors in the console? Did you try to fix them?

Comment: I'm trying to validate the textbox if its empty. So in the .js file I'm calling a function and validating the textbox in the function then passing it over to HTML and put it in the input of the text box and I also get a function to call the error message which comes into play when the submit button is clicked. However the current code I'm using is working for me at the moment.

Comment: *" However the current code I'm using is working for me at the moment."* Do you mean **not** working? If yes, what *exactly* doesn not work? `validateAll` is not called? `first` is not called? The value is not replaced? etc

Comment: Yes sorry. ValidateAll() is called in the onClick button and first is called in the input text box in onBlur. When I click submit I should be getting an alert saying enter name, but it won't appear. I did change it up as hinted at the button by alex, but still won't give me the alert.

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>

<head>

<title></title>

<script type="text/javascript">
var error = "";
function first(first)
{
    if(first.value == "")
    {
        error = "Please enter your name";
        first.focus();
    }

    return first;
}
function validateAll()
{
    if (error.length>0)
    {
        alert(error);
        return false;
    }
}

</script>
</head>

<body>

<p>First Name*: <input type="textbox" name="first" id="first"
    onBlur="this.value=this.value.trim(); first(this)"
    onkeyup='this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();'></p>

<p><input type="button" value="Proccess Payment"
    onClick="return validateAll();" /></p>

</body>

</html>
```

Try this and compare with your code.

Comment: Still no luck won't give me the alert.

Comment: Its worked correctly in my side, you just need to copy code and save as a html file

Comment: Moreover, you need to first click in text box then only the alert will work as you are setting the variable 'error' in method which called onBlur...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7NDtZ/   - try this, the textbox will need to get focus before button clicked.

Comment: Oh I see that now, is there way around? Like another event? Basically what I need is that .js functions I can take and use on other forms with the function and not just one form, hence why I'm trying to get this code.

Comment: There are so many libraries available for javascript validation, https://www.google.co.in/search?q=form+validation+using+javascript&rlz=1C1CHMO_en-GBIN570IN570&oq=form+validation+&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l5.7154j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=form+validation+library+in+javascript

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would ask that you dont use the same name for a function and it's parameters as you did with "first."

```
function first(first)  ---->  function setFocus(element)
```

Secondly, it looks like you are checking to see if the parameter, that you pass into the "first" function, is empty and then setting focus.  I'm pretty sure you want see of the element is not empty.

```
if(first == "")    ---->  if(element != "")
```

Thirdly, you should consolidate the trim operation into an appropriate callback.  At the moment trim is ran for every click, but you do not have any code that uses that value.  So, when you have a function that needs the input value, trim the value in that code.

Comment: Yeah I was looking into that. I had this form done and fully working however I got instruction to do a different way that way I can use the .js file for other forms, so I decided to try it this way. I did try to that method you pointed out still not quite working. I do have a function for trim not posted here, but it is in my JavaScriptif thats what you were wondering.

Comment: Ohh I think I finally understand what the code is supposed to be.  Take a look at this fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/5jM6M/2/, I updated the function to be assigned to a name, which will force the declaration of those function on the global object.

Comment: There is still a bug related to the trim() function, but I'm willing to let you figure that one out :)  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim

Comment: In the jsfiddle its not giving me the error message. As far as trim goes http://jsfiddle.net/5jM6M/2/ thats what I have when I did this as declaring the function as one it worked fine.

Comment: I still see this error in that fiddle.                             Uncaught ReferenceError: trim is not defined (index):46
onblur (index):46

Comment: Here is a tip to make debugging easier in Fiddle, go here http://jsfiddle.net/5jM6M/2/show.  Then remove the "show" directory from the url and hit enter.

Comment: ok thanks. I just wanted to ask you the error(alert) isn't coming up even in JSFiddle, is it because of the trim?

Comment: Yes, it i because of the trim function, specifically how it's being used.

Comment: instead of this.value=trim(this.value) would trim(this.value work)?

Comment: or in the function as the error message would it be better to trim?

Comment: Well, trim is a child of the String object.  All Strings in JS have the trim child as well, through prototype inheritance.  You would need to call String.trim(), but that is going to return a new string, so you can do this.value = this.value.trim();

Comment: Oh, so I had a bit reverse? the first time. Odd it did work for me the other way I validate.